# Translucent Navigation Bar & Tab Bar Now returning Black colour and not clear colour?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Everything was working great. Following apple designs i adopted a translucent navigation bar and tab bar.

In storyboard i have:-
Style - Defualt

Translucent ticked

Bar Tint - clear Color.

The background/main view is not set to  black

However since installing the xcode 5.1 update it now returns as a black translucent and not clear?

Anybody experience the same and what resolution did you discover?

Thanks for your help.